# Android Webview is not loading

Tags: javascript, android

I'm trying to make an app that opens a `webview`, the url that opens own `css` and `js` files, `css` opens normally, but the `js` does not open at all. 
I tried some functions like `OnPageLoad`, `webclient` and still not got positive result, I'm running on `android 4.1.2`, but when run the same project in `android 4.4.2` it works .. js file loads and the app works perfectly .. What can I do to make it work in `4.1.2` too?

my code

```
    public class Activity2 extends Activity {

WebView webView;
Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    webView = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webView);
context = this;
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);


try {
    InputStream stream = this.getAssets().open("coresAPP.html");
    int streamSize = stream.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[streamSize];
    stream.read(buffer);
    stream.close();
    String html = new String(buffer);
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

}
catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();

     }
  }

}
```

EDIT

```
(function(g,p,n){function v(a)      if(g.event&&g.event.contentOverflow!==n)return{x:g.event.offsetX,y:g.event.offsetY};if(a.off  setX!==n&&a.offsetY!==n)return{x:a.offsetX,y:a.offsetY};var b=a.target.parentNode.parentNode;return{x:a.layerX-b.offsetLeft,y:a.layerY-b.offsetTop}}function e(a,b,c){a=p.createElementNS(z,a);for(var d in b)a.setAttribute(d,b[d]);"[object Array]"!=Object.prototype.toString.call(c)&&(c=[c]);b=0;for(d=c[0]&&c.length||0;b<d;b++)a.appendChild(c[b]);return a}function h(a){var b,c,d,
j,e=a.h%360/60;j=a.v*a.s;d=j*(1-Math.abs(e%2-1));b=c=a=a.v-j;e=~~e;b+=[j,d,0,0,d,j][e];c+=[d,j,j,d,0,0][e];a+=[0,0,d,j,j,d][e];d=Math.floor(255*b);c=Math.floor(255*c);a=Math.floor(255*a);return{r:d,g:c,b:a,hex:"#"+(16777216|a|c<<8|d<<16).toString(16).slice(1)}}function q(a){var b=a.r,c=a.g,d=a.b;if(1<a.r||1<a.g||1<a.b)b/=255,c/=255,d/=255;var e;a=Math.max(b,c,d);e=a-Math.min(b,c,d);b=60*((0==e?0:a==b?(c-d)/e+(c<d?6:0):a==c?(d-b)/e+2:(b-c)/e+4)%6);return{h:b,s:0==e?0:e/a,v:a}}function w(a,b,c){return function(d){d=
d||g.event;d=v(d);a.h=360*(d.y/b.offsetHeight)+s;a.s=a.v=1;var e=h({h:a.h,s:1,v:1});c.style.backgroundColor=e.hex;a.callback&&a.callback(e.hex,{h:a.h-s,s:a.s,v:a.v},{r:e.r,g:e.g,b:e.b},n,d)}}function x(a,b){return function(c){c=c||g.event;c=v(c);var d=b.offsetHeight;a.s=c.x/b.offsetWidth;a.v=(d-c.y)/d;d=h(a);a.callback&&a.callback(d.hex,{h:a.h-s,s:a.s,v:a.v},{r:d.r,g:d.g,b:d.b},c)}}function f(a,b,c){if(!(this instanceof f))return new f(a,b,c);this.h=0;this.v=this.s=1;if(c)this.callback=c,this.pickerElement=
b,this.slideElement=a;else{a.innerHTML=A;this.slideElement=a.getElementsByClassName("slide")[0];this.pickerElement=a.getElementsByClassName("picker")[0];var d=a.getElementsByClassName("slide-indicator")[0],e=a.getElementsByClassName("picker-indicator")[0];f.fixIndicators(d,e);this.callback=function(a,c,g,h,k){f.positionIndicators(d,e,k,h);b(a,c,g)}}"SVG"==t?(a=k.getElementsByTagName("linearGradient")[0],c=k.getElementsByTagName("rect")[0],a.id="gradient-hsv-"+r,c.setAttribute("fill","url(#"+a.id+
")"),a=l.getElementsByTagName("linearGradient"),c=l.getElementsByTagName("rect"),a[0].id="gradient-black-"+r,a[1].id="gradient-white-"+r,c[0].setAttribute("fill","url(#"+a[1].id+")"),c[1].setAttribute("fill","url(#"+a[0].id+")"),this.slideElement.appendChild(k.cloneNode(!0)),this.pickerElement.appendChild(l.cloneNode(!0)),r++):(this.slideElement.innerHTML=k,this.pickerElement.innerHTML=l);m(this.slideElement,"click",w(this,this.slideElement,this.pickerElement));m(this.pickerElement,"click",x(this,
this.pickerElement));y(this,this.slideElement,w(this,this.slideElement,this.pickerElement));y(this,this.pickerElement,x(this,this.pickerElement))}function m(a,b,c){a.attachEvent?a.attachEvent("on"+b,c):a.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener(b,c,!1)}function y(a,b,c){var d=!1;m(b,"mousedown",function(){d=!0});m(b,"mouseup",function(){d=!1});m(b,"mouseout",function(){d=!1});m(b,"mousemove",function(a){d&&c(a)})}function u(a,b,c,d){a.h=b.h%360;a.s=b.s;a.v=b.v;b=h(a);var e={y:a.h*a.slideElement.offsetHeight/
360,x:0},f=a.pickerElement.offsetHeight,f={x:a.s*a.pickerElement.offsetWidth,y:f-a.v*f};a.pickerElement.style.backgroundColor=h({h:a.h,s:1,v:1}).hex;a.callback&&a.callback(d||b.hex,{h:a.h,s:a.s,v:a.v},c||{r:b.r,g:b.g,b:b.b},f,e);return a}var t=g.SVGAngle||p.implementation.hasFeature("http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#BasicStructure","1.1")?"SVG":"VML",l,k,s=15,z="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",A='<div class="picker-wrapper"><div class="picker"></div><div class="picker-indicator"></div></div><div class="slide-wrapper"><div class="slide"></div><div class="slide-indicator"></div></div>';
"SVG"==t?(k=e("svg",{xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",version:"1.1",width:"100%",height:"100%"},[e("defs",{},e("linearGradient",{id:"gradient-hsv",x1:"0%",y1:"100%",x2:"0%",y2:"0%"},[e("stop",{offset:"0%","stop-color":"#FF0000","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"13%","stop-color":"#FF00FF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"25%","stop-color":"#8000FF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"38%","stop-color":"#0040FF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"50%","stop-color":"#00FFFF","stop-opacity":"1"}),
e("stop",{offset:"63%","stop-color":"#00FF40","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"75%","stop-color":"#0BED00","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"88%","stop-color":"#FFFF00","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"100%","stop-color":"#FF0000","stop-opacity":"1"})])),e("rect",{x:"0",y:"0",width:"100%",height:"100%",fill:"url(#gradient-hsv)"})]),l=e("svg",{xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",version:"1.1",width:"100%",height:"100%"},[e("defs",{},[e("linearGradient",{id:"gradient-black",x1:"0%",
y1:"100%",x2:"0%",y2:"0%"},[e("stop",{offset:"0%","stop-color":"#000000","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"100%","stop-color":"#CC9A81","stop-opacity":"0"})]),e("linearGradient",{id:"gradient-white",x1:"0%",y1:"100%",x2:"100%",y2:"100%"},[e("stop",{offset:"0%","stop-color":"#FFFFFF","stop-opacity":"1"}),e("stop",{offset:"100%","stop-color":"#CC9A81","stop-opacity":"0"})])]),e("rect",{x:"0",y:"0",width:"100%",height:"100%",fill:"url(#gradient-white)"}),e("rect",{x:"0",y:"0",width:"100%",height:"100%",
fill:"url(#gradient-black)"})])):"VML"==t&&(k='<DIV style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%"><v:rect style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" stroked="f" filled="t"><v:fill type="gradient" method="none" angle="0" color="red" color2="red" colors="8519f fuchsia;.25 #8000ff;24903f #0040ff;.5 aqua;41287f #00ff40;.75 #0bed00;57671f yellow"></v:fill></v:rect></DIV>',l='<DIV style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%"><v:rect style="position: absolute; left: -1px; top: -1px; width: 101%; height: 101%" stroked="f" filled="t"><v:fill type="gradient" method="none" angle="270" color="#FFFFFF" opacity="100%" color2="#CC9A81" o:opacity2="0%"></v:fill></v:rect><v:rect style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 101%" stroked="f" filled="t"><v:fill type="gradient" method="none" angle="0" color="#000000" opacity="100%" color2="#CC9A81" o:opacity2="0%"></v:fill></v:rect></DIV>',
p.namespaces.v||p.namespaces.add("v","urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml","#default#VML"));var r=0;f.hsv2rgb=function(a){a=h(a);delete a.hex;return a};f.hsv2hex=function(a){return h(a).hex};f.rgb2hsv=q;f.rgb2hex=function(a){return h(q(a)).hex};f.hex2hsv=function(a){return q(f.hex2rgb(a))};f.hex2rgb=function(a){return{r:parseInt(a.substr(1,2),16),g:parseInt(a.substr(3,2),16),b:parseInt(a.substr(5,2),16)}};f.prototype.setHsv=function(a){return u(this,a)};f.prototype.setRgb=function(a){return u(this,q(a),
a)};f.prototype.setHex=function(a){return u(this,f.hex2hsv(a),n,a)};f.positionIndicators=function(a,b,c,d){c&&(b.style.left="auto",b.style.right="0px",b.style.top="0px",a.style.top=c.y-a.offsetHeight/2+"px");d&&(b.style.top=d.y-b.offsetHeight/2+"px",b.style.left=d.x-b.offsetWidth/2+"px")};f.fixIndicators=function(a,b){b.style.pointerEvents="none";a.style.pointerEvents="none"};g.ColorPicker=f})  (window,window.document);
```

Comment: do you get any errors or messages in logcat?

Comment: also please try to add the following: `webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Comment: 02-21 18:52:03.760: E/Web Console(597): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined at file:///android_asset/js/colorpicker.js:4

Comment: I think this is the problem .. any suggestions?

Comment: please show the code around error

Comment: sorry i'm new to android, how i can do that ? i think is somewhere around the "try" function when its load the html page in asset folder,

Comment: i mean code around here colorpicker.js:4

Comment: u mean whats is inside the colorpiker.js file ?

Comment: i put the colorpiker.js on EDIT Part ..it dont let me put as code ..the file is a mess sorry

Comment: what if to try the following: `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);try {
    Thread.sleep(300);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
};webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`

Comment: ill try it .. just a few mins

Comment: no results .. i cant understand why its works in 4.4.2 and not on 4.1.2 ... theres a way to load the js file using the method OnPageLoad ?

Comment: well, you can try to load js files at onPageFinished (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) and then call loadURL inside

Comment: ok bro .. thanks a lot for you help .. i'll keep researching